# Django model_mommy model instance isn't saved in Ajax test

Tags: django, django-testing, model-mommy

I'm trying to test an django ajax view that saves a field.  Here's the test:

```
def test_ajax_save_draft(self):
    self.client.force_login(self.test_user) # view requires login
    sub = mommy.make(QuestSubmission, quest=self.quest2)
    draft_comment = "Test draft comment"
    # Send some draft data via the ajax view, which should save it.
    ajax_data = {
        'comment': draft_comment,
        'submission_id': sub.id,
    }

    self.client.post(
        reverse('quests:ajax_save_draft'), 
        data=ajax_data,
        HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest',
    )

    self.assertEqual(draft_comment, sub.draft_text) # sub.draft_text = None, as if the ajax view was never called!
```

And here's the view:

```
@login_required
def ajax_save_draft(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:

        submission_comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        submission_id = request.POST.get('submission_id')

        sub = get_object_or_404(QuestSubmission, pk=submission_id)
        sub.draft_text = submission_comment
        sub.save()

        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'Draft saved'

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    else:
        raise Http404
```

When I run the test, I get into the if block, and it can retrieve the comment and submission object, but when it returns to the test at the end, it's like the save never happened.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling [`sub.refresh_from_db()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)

Changes made to a model instance will only affect the instance being modified. Any existing model instances will not be updated, `refresh_from_db` will get the changes from the database

Comment: No luck.  Still `None` after `refresh_from_db`

Comment: Check the response from your post

Comment: ARGH!  Thank you! it was 302ing because the view requires logging in.  I had that in there before but took it out for some reason.  `sub.refresh_from_db()` DOES fix the problem.